# SQL Nested Group By, First row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I need your help. I have table with DateTime and Person columns. Each person has multiple records for each date. I need to get first record for each person for each date. I suppose that nested group by should be used, but I dont know how to implement that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it first record for each person for each "DATE" in your datetime, or is it multiple records per person per datetime entry?

Answer (score 3):

Your can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) together with the [OVER clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
SELECT   *
FROM
(
    SELECT       Your_Columns,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person, [DateTime] ORDER BY Your_Column_That_Decides_The_Order_Of_Records) AS R
    FROM         Your_Table
) v
WHERE v.R = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the row_number and other ranking functions that sql server offers for this. Really useful tools for you to use in other scenarios as well
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use min(date/time) column and remaining column in group by.